# Storage Pools: replacing a disk without deleting the "simple" virtual disk

Tags: powershell, storage-spaces, windows-server-2016

```
Disk A: 100GB
Disk B: 200GB
Disk C: 400GB
```

Suppose I had created a 300GB pool using `A` and `B`. Then, I created a "simple" virtual disk on it, whose size is 300GB. Then, I only have 10GB data files on that volume. Logically, it is not impossible to add `C` to the pool and then remove `A`, while keeping the virtual disk. The System can just copy the data from `A` to `C` before `A`'s removal.

I tried this with the Storage Spaces of Windows 10, and it worked as I expected. But when I tried it on Windows Server 2016, the popup message said the virtual disk must be deleted.

If Storage Spaces can do, I think Storage Pool could do that too. Is there a way, or is it impossible on Storage Pools?

Comment: The GUI (I use win2012R2) is very quirky. Last time I tried to add a simple v.disk when there were 3TB free in pool, but it refused, saying not enough space. I could create only one with size of about 600 GB. Then immediately after that I tried to create another simple disk with 2.4 TB and it succeeded without a hitch. Not a good vibe from a system to which you trust your data.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research... The following worked. I had to use the PowerShell.

1. Get the disk a unique thing to point the disk.
   `Get-PhysicalDisk` may do it, but if there same FriendlyNames or SerialNumber is empty, run `Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object UniqueID` to get the GUID.
2. Retire the disk to remove. If `-UniqueID` is omitted it takes the next argument as a FriendlyName.
   `Set-PhysicalDisk -UniqueID "....." -Usage Retired`
3. Open the Server Manager. Go to Storage Pools. Right-click the disk to remove and select `Remove Disk`.

Then it does not say the virtual disk needs to be removed. It says that Windows is repairing the affected virtual disks. I checked the virtual disk volume after the removal of the disk. The volume was marked as `healthy` and I could see the files were intact.

I wonder why this 'retiring' is not available in the GUI.

Comment: Mark answer accepted so that this doesn't hang around 'unanswered'.  Nice work.